# MapsApi - Google maps place service giving a weird error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Google maps place service not working properly and giving the next error

> Uncaught Error: Property radius is invalid. A possible cause is that the value conflicts with other properties.

Code

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var request = {
    location: centerLatLong,
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    radius: 500
}; 
service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status){
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
        console.log(results)
    }
});
```

Comment: what's mean `reque'enter code here'st` in service.nearbySearch() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `radius`-property is not supported when you use `rankBy:distance`.

The documentation for the Javascript-API seems to be incomplete, because it doesn't contain a information that the radius-property is **not allowed** when you use `rankBy:distance` , but the documentation for the places-Webservice contains this information:

> `radius` — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place
>   results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. **Note that radius
>   must not be included if rankby=distance** (described under Optional
>   parameters below) is specified.

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Solution: remove the `radius`-property